# How to open docker-compose services in separate shells

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook + elastic docker-compose like so:

```
    version: "3"
      services:
        jupyter:
          build: . #ubuntu
          ports:
            - 8888:8888
          .....
          entrypoint: jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root

        elasticsearch:
          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
          .....
          depends_on:
            - jupyter

        ..... (logstash + kibana)
```

The problem is jupyter spits out a token needed to use it:

```
The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
jupyter_1 http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=....
```

but quickly gets buried from all the elastic output to the shell. It becomes a pain to scroll up and find the token. How can I make the jupyter service open in a new shell separate from from other services so the token is easy to grab?

Comment: find container id from `docker ps` output, then try `docker logs <container-id> | grep -A1 'to login with a token'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

`docker-compose up -d`

`docker-compose logs jupyter | grep token`

If you want to follow logs again you can run

`docker-compose logs -f`

Or

Just open another terminal and run

`docker logs jupyter | grep token`